Invalid parameter on netsh http add
All the ways end at the same point "Invalid parameter" referring to appid (Guid). If I remove that parameter, the adding process can finish correctly.
These are the some commands I have been trying until now:

Direct commands

   netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:9005 certhash=a80cbaa0357d02c9da654b5bfdd79ceaae7770d2 appid=90fcf56d-118a-495b-897f-ac5fa0c53b14

   netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:9005 certhash=a80cbaa0357d02c9da654b5bfdd79ceaae7770d2 appid={90fcf56d-118a-495b-897f-ac5fa0c53b14}

   netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:9005 certhash=a80cbaa0357d02c9da654b5bfdd79ceaae7770d2 appid='{90fcf56d-118a-495b-897f-ac5fa0c53b14}'

   netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:9005 certhash=a80cbaa0357d02c9da654b5bfdd79ceaae7770d2 appid="{90fcf56d-118a-495b-897f-ac5fa0c53b14}"


Changing order:

   netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:9005 appid=90fcf56d-118a-495b-897f-ac5fa0c53b14 certhash=a80cbaa0357d02c9da654b5bfdd79ceaae7770d2


Using variables

   $guid = \[guid\]::NewGuid()

   $Command = "http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:9005 certhash=a80cbaa0357d02c9da654b5bfdd79ceaae7770d2 appid={$guid}"

   $Command | netsh

Edit: After some tries, I began to receive Error 1312, as follows:
Error al agregar el certificado SSL. Error: 1312
Una sesión de inicio especificada no existe. Es posible que haya finalizado.
As Luuk has answered me later, I realized that the problem was that the certificate had not private key and so, it couldn't be related with any ipport using sslcert.

See the examples, at the end of: netsh http add sslcert  (HINT: use {} around the appid)

Hi Luuk, I already used them. Point 1, row 2.    netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:9005 certhash=a80cbaa0357d02c9da654b5bfdd79ceaae7770d2 appid={90fcf56d-118a-495b-897f-ac5fa0c53b14}

I tried with this another option. I'm using quotes due to e character lies to powershell. netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:9005 certhash=a80cbaa0357d02c9da654b5bfdd79ceaae7770d2 appid="{123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000}"
Now I have Error 1312, but I don't know if it's an step forward or back.

Do some research on "Error 1312", and look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1180711/ssl-certificate-add-failed-error-1312 .   Please always use [edit] to improve the question with the detailed error message.

I finally got it. These are the steps I followed:
#1-Crear certificado
#1-Creating selfsigned certificate
New-SelfSignedCertificate -certstorelocation cert:\localmachine\my -dnsname dmname.localhost.com

#****************************************************************************************************************
#Notas, tras varias pruebas, he visto que es obligatorio que el certificado final tenga clave privada añadida.
#After some tries, I realized that the certificate must be signed to be related with any application when we're using netsh.
#****************************************************************************************************************
#2-Se hace la relación con el footprint devuelto por el paso anterior que representa el certificado con la dirección:puerto de nuestra aplicación
#2- Making relation between certificate and service point
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:9005 certhash=C29F0ACC2AC4882835C8E027582DDC18971A36B3 appid="{123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440001}"

Appid quotes are needed because it's required to scape the expression "-e89b"
#3- Check reserved URLs
netsh http show urlacl

#4-Reserve url netsh http add urlacl
url=https://dmname.localhost.com:9005/ user=Users

